# How to change my residence address for NEXUS?

Tags: usa, canada, nexus, trusted-traveler

I need to change the residence address associated with my NEXUS trusted traveler account (for US/Canada border crossings). I was trying to follow the [US CBP instructions](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1342/kw/Nexus%20address%20change/suggested/1), but they don't work (I see the "Update Document" link, but it only lets me change passport and driver's license information, not the address). The [Canadian instructions](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/contact-coordonnees-eng.html) are vague. I see an "Update Mail-To Address" link in the GOES system, but unsurprisingly it only updates the mailing address, not the residence address.

Is there actually a way to update the address online? If not, what's the correct way to update the address - do I need to physically visit an enrollment center?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/817/~/i-am-enrolled-in-a-trusted-traveler-program.-do-i-have-to-notify-you-if-i):

> **I am enrolled in a Trusted Traveler Program. Do I have to notify you
>   if I change my address?**
>
> Yes. If the mailing address that you originally submitted for the
>   NEXUS/SENTRI/Global Entry program has changed, you can login to your
>   GOES account to update it. On the welcome screen on the left hand side
>   you will see a link to update your Mail-to Address.
>
> **You will need to go to the nearest Enrollement Center to update your
>   residential/permanent address**.  No appointment is needed, but please
>   contact the Enrollment Center first.

Comment: There is a contradiction here. Updating your address means you "login" to the site and "update it" and also "go to the nearest Enrollement Center" to "update your address" So which is it?

Comment: @podcastfan88: Both Residential address and Mail-To address can be updated at an Enrollment Center. Only Mail-To address can be updated online.